# Too short control escape. How to get Regex for this?

Tags: c#, regex

So, let's say I have a result from a search that comes back as:

```
\\my.test.site@SSL\JohnDoe\SusanSmith\courses\PDFs\Science_Math\BIOL\S12014 Syllabi\BIOL-1322-S12014-John-Doe.pdf
```

Whenever the result is listed in a text box I get the entire path instead of just the file. This is functioning as designed since I can't use the `.Select(Path.GetFileName)` while enumerating directories lest it doesn't have the full path to do the search on.

So, I was going to use Regex to do a replace at the end when the results are displayed however when I went to Rubular it doesn't like either my expression or the test string(can't figure out which).

I basically want to cut down everything except the file name and extension.

So my Regex was supposed to be something like:

```
\\my.test.site@SSL\JohnDoe\SusanSmith\courses\PDFs\.+\.+\.+\
```

So that I get everything up to the file name and extension for deletion. However Rubular doesn't like something as I get a "too short control escape" error. I don't want to test this in C# without verifying in Rubular since I use it heavily and figure if it won't work there it won't work at runtime.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Just use `@"\\my.test.site@SSL\JohnDoe\SusanSmith\courses\PDFs\.+\.+\.+\"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember to escape the `\` characters, as well as the literal `.` characters:

```
\\\\my\.test\.site@SSL\\JohnDoe\\SusanSmith\\courses\\PDFs\\.+\\.+\\.+\\
```

Also note, you probably want to avoid over-matching on the `.+` by using non-greedy quantifiers:

```
\\\\my\.test\.site@SSL\\JohnDoe\\SusanSmith\\courses\\PDFs\\.+?\\.+?\\.+?\\
```

Or using character classes:

```
\\\\my\.test\.site@SSL\\JohnDoe\\SusanSmith\\courses\\PDFs\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\[^\\]+\\
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question, but it sounds like your approach has been overly complicated.

Can't you simply match this: `.+\\`

And then replace with `''` (nothing)?